# SilverLight Binding Grid ColSpan

Tags: silverlight, binding, grid, html-table

Can we use Binding for Grid ColSpan/RowSpan?

For example,

```
<StackPanel Grid.ColSpan={Binding ColSpanValue} />
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I had one of those very informative xaml parser errors, which I assumed was due to my binding. After I saw the below comment, I went back to check and found an issue in my style. All is well now! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**:

You can bind on any dependency property. Attached properties like Grid.ColSpan are by necessity DependencyProperties.

In the case of ColSpan it is defined by the Grid class, but the actual values are stored within the properties of the object that it is applied to.